# How to add country flag in the html input tag?

Tags: php

I want to add country flag in html input tag and yeah bootstrap helper can do it. But i do not know how to add the links and scripts exactly that would solve my issue. So any help ?

Comment: please give a brief explanation and at least a code snippet that you have started. The community will keep on downvoting your question if you just ask for something without trying anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need

Only Bootstrap and Jquery can't do that, https://github.com/mojoaxel/bootstrap-select-country/releases/tag/v3.1.0 is a Jquery Plugin to populate Select with Country name and Flag

This is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bootstrap Select Country</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//mojoaxel.github.io/bootstrap-select-country/dist/css/bootstrap-select-country.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <select class="selectpicker countrypicker" data-flag="true" ></select>
    </form>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//mojoaxel.github.io/bootstrap-select-country/dist/js/bootstrap-select-country.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```